# Flutter Error when implementing google_mobile_ads

Tags: flutter, dart, ads, google-mobile-ads

I've been trying to implement `google_mobile_ads` by following these instructions: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-ads-in-flutter#3

- I got this error when trying to run the app in VSCode:

  ```
  Error (Xcode): Framework not found GoogleAppMeasurement
  ```
- The only thing that works is removing the dependency `google_mobile_ads: ^3.0.0` from `pubspec.yaml`
- I added my application ids from `admob` correctly into the `Info.plist` and `AndroidManifest.xml`, and my files are not being stored in iCloud.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to update macOS and reinstall pods with pod install and accept some new Xcode agreements. Sooooo annoying!